# How to replace the string from any specific word till end of the string through regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanna replace the string-specific word till the end of the string through regex but got nothing as the desired output.

String: `Parameter: Input: 'Hello', code: 81279`

After using the described regex I got the following output.

```js
string.replace(/(code:).+?((?=\",)|(?=\"}))/gi, '').
```

Output: `Parameter: Input: 'Hello', code: 81279`

Expected Output: `Parameter: Input: 'Hello',`

Comment: Why do you use a blockquote for the only relevant code part, but inline code tags for something that's not really code? o.O

Comment: You regex searches for strings ending with either `",` or `"}`, see https://regexr.com/63d8p. You can use a tool like https://regexr.com/ to work with regular expressions.

Comment: `"'Hello', code: 81279".replace(/\s*(?:code:).+/gi, '')` would do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex searches for strings ending with either `",` or `"}`. You can just remove `((?=\",)|(?=\"}))`, use a non-lazy operator and search for spaces in front of `code`:

```js
const string = "Parameter: Input: 'Hello', code: 81279";
console.log(string.replace(/ *code:.+/gi, ''));
```

Comment: Thank you @jabaa for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? Matching the `"` character won't work as it don't exist in the string.

```js
var string = "Parameter: Input: 'Hello', code: 81279";
string = string.replace(/(code:).+?$/gi, '');
console.log(string);
```

Note that there is a trailing white space, i.e. `Parameter: Input: 'Hello',`

Comment: Thank you @Anson Yeung for the help.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the part that you need with using regex pattern as the part that enclosed your needed pattern.
you can use this pattern for example:

```
string.replace(/(code:).+?$/gi, '')
```

the js fiddle also shows the result

```js
var string = "Parameter: Input: 'Hello', code: 81279";

var result = string.replace(/(code:).+?$/gi, '');

console.log(result)
```

you can also use sites like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) for testing your regex with a phrase

Comment: Thank you @Masoud for the help.